# AmCharts Gauge Balloon Tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, graph, charts, amcharts

How can I ad an balloon to an AmCharts Gauge?
Is this not possible?

How can I add an balloon tooltip to the arrow showing the value in percent?

Copied the markup from AmChart docs. But only seems to work with regular charts and not gauges.

http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmBalloon
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmAngularGauge

http://jsfiddle.net/shL0g1rc/2/

Code Sample

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "gauge",
  "arrows": [
    {
      "value": 130
    }
  ],
  "titles": [
    {
      "text": "Speedometer",
      "size": 15
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "bottomText": "0 km/h",
      "endValue": 220,
      "valueInterval": 10,
      "bands": [
        {
          "color": "#00CC00",
          "endValue": 90,
          "startValue": 0
        },
        {
          "color": "#ffac29",
          "endValue": 130,
          "startValue": 90
        },
        {
          "color": "#ea3838",
          "endValue": 220,
          "startValue": 130,
          "innerRadius": "95%"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "balloon": {
    "adjustBorderColor": true,
    "color": "#000000",
    "cornerRadius": 5,
    "fillColor": "#FFFFFF"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`balloonText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/GaugeBand#balloonText) on your gauge band to display the balloon.

You can also use "rendered" event, to dynamically update `balloonText` so it reflects the arrow values.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "gauge",
  "arrows": [
    {
      "value": 130,
      "title": "Speed"
    }
  ],
  "titles": [
    {
      "text": "Speedometer",
      "size": 15
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "bottomText": "0 km/h",
      "endValue": 220,
      "valueInterval": 10,
      "bands": [
        {
          "color": "#00CC00",
          "endValue": 90,
          "startValue": 0,
          "balloonText": "Good"
        },
        {
          "color": "#ffac29",
          "endValue": 130,
          "startValue": 90,
          "balloonText": "Careful"
        },
        {
          "color": "#ea3838",
          "endValue": 220,
          "startValue": 130,
          "innerRadius": "95%",
          "balloonText": "Too Fast!"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "balloon": {
    "adjustBorderColor": true,
    "color": "#000000",
    "cornerRadius": 5,
    "fillColor": "#FFFFFF"
  },
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "rendered",
    "method": function(event) {
      var chart = event.chart;
      var text = "";
      for(var i = 0; i < chart.arrows.length; i++) {
        var arrow = chart.arrows[i];
        text += arrow.title + ": " + arrow.value + "<br />";
      }
      for(var i = 0; i < chart.axes[0].bands.length; i++) {
        chart.axes[0].bands[i].balloonText = text;
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/gauge.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: thx. I like to add the balloon tooltip to the arrow though. Is this possible too?

Comment: Hm, no I'm afraid. It would make a good feature though. I'll make sure it's in the TODO list for future version. We'll let you know when this is implemented.

Comment: Thx. I guess you send me an email in case its beeing implemented. Is it possible to show values for all arrows in the gauge axis balloon?

Comment: We will. Balloon contents is HTML, so you can put anything there. And you can update it dynamically. Let me update my answer.

Comment: It would be a great feature to add, the chart is imprecise by nature, so I expect users will want to hover to see the exact value — and it is missing (hovering bands is not intuitive, I'd never checked them for the value).